# How to return the maximum key in the symbol table

Tags: java, linked-list

This is what I have so far, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly. I am having trouble returning the maxKey for the unordered linked list:

```
public class LinkedListST<Key extends Comparable<Key>, Value> {
    private Node first;
    private class Node {
        private Key key;
        private Value val;
        private Node next;

    public Node(Key key, Value val, Node next)  {
        this.key  = key;
        this.val  = val;
        this.next = next;
    }
}

public Key maxKey (Key key) {
    Node currentNode = null;    //current node we are on
    if (first == null)
        return null;
    for(currentNode = first; currentNode != null; currentNode = currentNode.next){

        }
    return null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare all the keys and find the biggest

```
public Key maxKey () {
    Node currentNode = null;    //current node we are on
    if (first == null)
        return null;
    Key<Comparable> max = first.key;
    do {
      currentNode = currentNode.next;
      if (currentNode == null) break;
      if (currentNode.key.compareTo(max) > 0) {
        max = currentNode.key;
      }
    while (true);
    return max;
}
```

Comment: What would the code look like if it had no arguments taking in?

Comment: Adjusted to show the method with no arguments... It is the same code, as I never used the `Key` parameter originally

Comment: its still failing my program it says "Fails on the LinkedList created by successive put of the below key value pairs:
# of puts = 1, key-value pairs = (ZS, 160)" and I actually don't understand what that means